# How do I connect asp.net mvc to a non-local mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I have added this connection information into both the Webconfig in the same file level as the views folder, and the one in the views folder. It is also in the Web.Debug.config.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MySqlServer"
connectionString="Datasource=foo.bar.net;Database=testasp;uid=Slendy;pwd=istall;"
    providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

And then I have this function I copy pasted from a how-to that crashes on adapter.Fill(ds) because of a MySqlException "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." when I open /data/details/1

```
//
    // GET: /Data/Details
    public string Details()
    {
        // Get the MySQL connection string stored in the Web.config
        string cnnString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

        // Create a connection object and data adapter
        MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        // Create a SQL command object
        string cmdText = "select '3232' as ah;";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnx);

        // Set the command type to StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Create and fill a DataSet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        return "::::";
    }
```

My test sql table is on my website rather than localhost, and is as follows

```
a   b   c
1   2013-02-02 14:08:53 324
2   2013-02-02 14:08:53 342234
```

I had followed a guide here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html but am not sure if I found the right file to edit. I also set permission on dreamhost for my computer to access it.

Update: cnnString is coming up NULL

Comment: it shouldn't be any harder than that :\

Comment: That's what I thought. Perhaps I didn't edit the right machine.config file. A search on my pc turns up 86 results.

Comment: oy. between web.config's and web.debug.config's, these things can be a pain. Find it in your solution explorer. Otherwise, I wish I had what to add. It's a routine issue every time AND you're not doing anything thats clearly wrong.

Comment: Hmmm... If all else fails you could create a tunnel - example using Putty http://homer.netsal.selu.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Creating_a_SSH_tunnel_to_MySql_using_PuTTY_-_Tyler_Hunt. You could also try an ODBC Provider to connect to the database. I have used this before to migrate a MySQL database to SQL Server http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29106/Migrate-MySQL-to-Microsoft-SQL-Server - but you could just do the ODBC setup steps and then connect to the database via ODBC in your application.

Comment: Also, my first port of call with these things is to check the Windows Application Event logs to see if the driver is reporting any errors, i.e. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997769(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: 3nigma asks a decent question there. In order to rule out any network issues, try connecting with something like Putty or the MySQL Workbench first.

Comment: I am not behind a proxy, and although I installed putty, I only have puttygen.exe come up in start8. ODBC is not something I want to turn to for my situation.  HOWEVER, I have noticed that cnnString is null. But I looked it up on msdn, and I don't know why.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Regarding putty, I generally don't 'install' putty, I just copy it somewhere and run it by double clicking on it. Since it's not 'installed', it probably doesn't show up in start8. One way to solve this would be to make a tile - http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-metro-tile.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that ConfigurationSettings should be ConfigurationManager and set the line of code to be

```
string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlServer"].ToString();
```

where "MySqlServer" matches the connectionstring name in the config file.

This was a good help:
[C# Configuration Manager . ConnectionStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828060/c-sharp-configuration-manager-connectionstrings)