# Get Connection String from Method returning Connection error Object Refrence not Set to the instance of object ??? Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, connection-string

i am trying to get connection string from method resulting error object reference not set to the instance object my method is,

this method return connection,

```
namespace InspectionServices.Services
{
    public class ConfigManager
    {
        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["***"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

and here i am getting connection by calling method mentioned above,

```
 string connectionString = InspectionServices.Services.ConfigManager.GetConnectionString();
```

hopes for your suggestion

Thanks in Advance

EDITED:

Appconfig,

```
 <connectionStrings> 
    <add name="Inspection" connectionString="Data Source=***;Database=***;Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=false; Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Please also show us your web.config file! Do you have a `<connectionStrings>` section in there? Does the connection string you want to load even exist in that section??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mush have web.config entries like this

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="name" connectionString="***" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Only then you can use it in your class.

Some useful links
[C# Configuration Manager . ConnectionStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828060/c-sharp-configuration-manager-connectionstrings)

http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/store-connection-string-in-web-config

Comment: i am getting error on object refrence not set to instance of object on the methos from where i am returning connection string

Comment: at which line is it in `return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["***"].ConnectionString;` line?

Comment: are you putting `***` or `Inspection` in the above line?

Comment: @ one thing i noticed that as i gave it index in place of name "inspection " it successfully get connection string then what would be the reason ???

Comment: It is case sensitive so be careful. You might be using `inspection` in place of `Inspection`

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace InspectionServices.Services
{
    public class ConfigManager
    {
        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Inspection"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```